# How can i use logic in Terraform for Azure?

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to build infrastructure based on a subscription in Azure. eg if my subscription is SUB_A i want it to use a set of variables for that subscription , if subscription is SUB_B then use another set?

What's the best way of doing this for Azure Terraform?

Comment: Your question is really unclear.  Can you give an example of specifically which values you want to change on which resources?  Even if it's just pseudocode or something to give us a better idea of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, you can achieve that using Terraform here, is the code for a sample example of deploying AKS clusters in one subscription and the DNS zone in another subscription.
- The other point is you need to have rights on both the subscriptions for the account which you are using for deployment
- First thing is we need to create Multiple AzureRM providers.
- And will run the deployments on both the subscriptions.
- Here is the [document](https://samcogan.com/deploying-to-multiple-azure-subscriptions-with-terraform/) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, but I think you are asking how to use variables to modify how your deploy is done based on arguments passed in when your apply your terraform.  That is what I'm going to answer.

One possible option is to use variables:

```
variable "environment" {
  type    = string
  default = "beta"
}

variable "location" {
  type    = string
  default = "West US"
}
```

For more information about how to use variables, refer to Terraform documentation on Input Variables: https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables

To allow further specifications you can use conditionals based on the variables you passed in:

```
condition ? true_val : false_val
```

You can find more information here:  https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/conditionals